# AppHarbor points my domain to www.hostname.com but not hostname.com

Tags: dns, hosting, appharbor

I'm interested in having my website show up for both of these urls - www.example.com and example.com.  DNS works properly and redirects www.example.com to 184.72.232.XXX and shows the website but not example.com.  I've tried 2 hostname setups:

1. www.example.com, canonical=true
2. *.example.com (unable to set canonical)

Both hostname configurations have the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add "example.com" too (and keep "*.example.com"). The wildcard only matches subdomains. If you want the www version to be the canonical hostname, you'll need to add that as well.